# How do I access, in PHP, the contents of a FormData submitted using fetch and the DELETE method?

Tags: php, rest

To delete a piece of content with my REST API, one sends a DELETE request with the id of the content. In my case, this is being done with the `whatwg-fetch` polyfill:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', this.props.id);
formData.append('csrfToken', this.props.csrfToken);

fetch('https://furkleindustries.com/twinepm/package/', {
    method: 'DELETE',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: formData,
});
```

With GET and POST, variables appear, respectively, in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals. However, DELETE variables, as far as I know, can only be captured through parsing `php://input`. Unfortunately, all this gives me is a single string containing the entirety of the `-----WebKitFormBoundary`-delimited request body, not an associative array of the arguments I sent with the request. How do I parse/access the DELETE variables from PHP, or if I can't, how do I use `fetch` with DELETE?

Comment: I remember doing something similar with angular and `$http` service and the solution was to json_decode either all of `php://input` or just a portion of it, sorry I can't remember more

Comment: @chiliNUT No, this was really helpful, it actually pointed me towards a solution. Thanks!

Comment: nice, I think under the hood angular have been stringifying my data for me, glad it helped you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to pass the data to the body parameter of `fetch`'s setup object as a JSON string, like so:

```
const params = {
    id: this.props.id,
    csrfToken: this.props.csrfToken,
};

fetch('https://furkleindustries.com/twinepm/package/', {
    method: 'DELETE',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(params),
});
```

Then the contents of `php://input` can be `json_decode`d and `$_POST` can be set to the result of that decoding. As far as I have been able to tell, it is not possible to send data through a FormData instance using the DELETE method and have it be automatically processed into an object or associative array in PHP.

Comment: php frameworks can do it "automagically", I believe Laravel does